# Passing Zipcode + 4 in query string

Tags: c#, query-string

I am trying to pass a zip code + 4 in my query string for a dialog box. When I pass:

```
?zip=12345-1234
```

It is evaluating it as a math problem and my dialog recieves it as

```
zip = 11111
```

Is there a way to pass the -(dash) in the zip code without it evaluating it as a math problem.

Comment: You need to properly encode it. For a - it should be replaced with %2D.

Comment: What have meant it to pass (show an example so it will be clearer)

Comment: What is the “it” that is evaluating your string “as a math problem”?

Comment: I already have the zip plus 4 which is 12345-1234 when i pass that value through the query string it(query string) is evaluating it as a math problem

Comment: Please show relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean zip="12345-1234"? (assuming zip is a string)

Or maybe: (if zip is an integer)

```
string sZip = zip.ToString();
sZip = sZip + "-1234";
```

What you wrote means Subtract 1234 from 12345. What I've wrote is "set zip to be the **string** '12345-1234'". If you don't know what is the different, you haven't understood the difference of int and string. You can learn in the internet the differences betwean different **types** of object or variables.